# Error in TLS version is Load runner script

Tags: loadrunner

im am trying to record a web http request for a pega payment gateway and im facing a issue with TLS versions used. For the pega development they have used TLS 1.1 and for the payment gatway it is TLS 1.2. So when im replaying the script im getting status code 403.
I guess this is because TLS 1.1 is not compatible for payment gateway..any idea from you guys..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should ask the Clients first which SSL version they have used for authentication and use the same in your scripts. Otherwise you can to do hit and trial. Use function web_set_sockets_option() with different arguments:
1. "2"
2. "3"
3. "2&3"
4. "TLS"
5. "TLS1.1"
6. "TLS1.2"